# build xcode project on jenkins using ubuntu server

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I configured the android app, and also i need to configure ios app using jenkins ci. The android works fine. But i found out that ios cant be built on unix based system, that it needs to be built only on mac os. I have ubuntu 16.04 server where jenkins is installed. How to build ios apps using it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot – iOS applications must be built with Xcode running on macOS.

Comment: how do you use ci for ios projects?

Comment: You run it on a macOS server or you use a third-party service such as [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io).

Comment: what about Bitrise is it free?

Comment: If you follow the link, you'll see a pricing section on their website.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add MAC box as and Jenkins slave node and run Xcode on that MAC box and run your build on that Jenkins slave node